Triggering Estimator.fit() from Lambda hangs
I'm trying to trigger a Sagemaker finetuning job from a AWS Lambda function like so:
    estmtr = Estimator(
        image_uri=ecr_image,
        role=role,
        base_job_name="lm-finetune",
        instance_count=cfg.INSTANCE_COUNT,
        instance_type=cfg.INSTANCE_TYPE,
        hyperparameters=hps
    )

    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H-%M")
    job_name = "lm-finetuner-" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + "-" + current_time

    logging.info(f"Starting training job: {job_name}")

    estmtr.fit(wait=False, job_name=job_name)

However, the code hangs indefinitely when it tries to instantiate estmr. How can I fix this?
I have S3FullAccess, SagemakerFullAcess and IAMFullAccess set up on the Lambda. This also works locally perfectly fine (i.e outside of a Lambda function).

My god, Python code is slow, it was literally just a issue of assigning more memory to the lambda.
